# Segfault at _IO_ getc when reading file

Tags: c, file, io, segmentation-fault

I'm working on setting up a basic CTF for my school and one of the challenges is to simply analyze the ASM (x86) of a binary, figure out how it works, and break it. This one is simple: push 37 arguments to it, you get escalted to a 'flag' user that reads the flag in the directory, and you get points.

However for some reason I get segfaulted when it gets to reading the flag.

Heres the code:

```
void readflag()
{
        setgid(1401);
        char ch;
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen("argcimapirate.flag", "r");
        while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
                printf("%c",ch);
        fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        printf("ARRRRRRR!\n");
        if (argc == 37)
        {
                printf("Shiver me timbers...\n");
                readflag();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Also, this is the output of ls -l to see the permissions.

```
-r-sr-s--- 1 argcimapirate argcimapirate 8811 Jul 13 15:58 argcimapirate
-r-------- 1 root          root           335 Jul 13 15:58 argcimapirate.c
-r--r----- 1 flag          flag            17 Jul 11 21:12 argcimapirate.flag
```

Any ideas, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: What's "CTF"? Presumably `fp` is `NULL` after the `fopen`. Why do you think user/group `argcimapirate` would have access to user/group `flag`?

Comment: Uh, where's the assembly?

Comment: 1.) This would get compiled and saved as a binary to be statically analyzed.

2.) I thought that the setgid would give them access to that file?

Comment: How do you know `gid 1401` is group flag?

Comment: I assigned it that when I made the usergroup /etc/passwd

Comment: Did you verify that setgid() succeded ? Changes are it fails. Did you check that fopen() succeeded ? Chances are ...

Comment: the definition of 'ch' needs to be 'int'.

Comment: Most likely the setgid() function fails because your gid/uid do not have the necessary permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it guys.

Turns out that the flag user needs to own the file in order for the setuid/setgid to escalate to a point where the user can read files that flag owns.